# The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.WebControls'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i'am trying to use ajaxcontroltoolkit in my asp.net web forms project. I have added the reference already and also added the kit to the toobox by using its dll that i got from NuGet. But when i try to run project i get this error. By the way i'am using visual studio 2012 ultimate.

Unknown Server Control Error

Here is my codes

```
                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TabPanel>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Add Category</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    <asp:TabPanel>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Add Brand</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    <asp:TabPanel>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Add Model</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    <asp:TabPanel>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Add Shoe</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                </asp:TabContainer>
```

I have google it already but i couldn't find any solution. I can add any neccesary information if you need. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does your page include the Register tag and has it been registered in web.config?

Comment: No it does, because the register tag that i found is not working right for me so i remove it. I'am looking for a correct one.

Comment: as mentioned in the link provided by @Metaphor you have to include a register tag <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan After i put this tag to the page all tags that start with "asp" have a warning which is "element is not known".

Comment: change the tagPrefix to to some other value like "ajax" and see if it works

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan now with "asp" the warnings are gone but when i try to display the page in browser, there is no tab container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53997/discussion-between-karthik-ganesan-and-tartar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Ajax Toolkit installed?

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Is the following line at the top of your page?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

If you do, try this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager...>
```

Comment: it' says "unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'ajax toolkit'"

Comment: As a said already, i have installed the package by using nuget.

Comment: Also others give the same warning.

Comment: I have this tag on my web.config already, do i have to add this(<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />) to to the start of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

It exists in the namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls;

But in order to use it you have to install AJAX toolkit.

And before Using a Control from AJAX toolkit you have to reister the toolkit script manager.

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

You can to do one more thing.

1.Remove the Ajax Control tab from the toolbox.

2.Re-add the tab and right-click on the tab, Select Choose Items and browse to the AjaxControltoolkit.dll file in your own project and press OK(make sure that you are using the same version of ajax toolkit as of your C# version).

3.Clean and rebuild the solution and you are ready to go.

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is this just below the form tag "asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" i.e. change "asp:ToolkitScriptManager" to simply "asp:ScriptManager" at least, for VS 2013.